# Bernoulli Theorem question

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

On a factory there are 60 percent women and 40 percent men. 0.4 of workers gain medium wage.  0.2 high wage, and 0.4 low wage. 6 workers are chosen among workers who do not gain medium wage. what is the probability that most of them will have low wage?

attempt at a  solution:

Applying the Bernoulli theorem:$P= {6 \choose 4} * (\frac{{0.2}}{0.6})^2 *  (\frac{{0.4}}{0.6})^4   + {6 \choose 5} * (\frac{{0.2}}{0.6})^1 *  (\frac{{0.4}}{0.6})^5 +{6 \choose 6} * (\frac{{0.2}}{0.6})^0 *  (\frac{{0.4}}{0.6})^6 = \frac{{256}}{729}  $

Is this right?

Comment: 0.4 percent, or 40 percent?

Comment: Yes indeed, 40.

Comment: what's the relevance of gender distribution for the problem? I mean how do you use the 60/40 breakdown? No information is provided on gender-based income distribution

Comment: @Arkamis I re-edited

Comment: @Alex There appears not to be one; it's just distractor data to make students' lives miserable.

Comment: @Alex Im not sure, that's how it was presented in the textbook.

Comment: The method is right. There was I think a computational slip. I get numerator $496$. But my mental calculations are not to be trusted.

Comment: @Alex Am I not getting the standardization when $0.4/0.6$ turns into $2/3$?

Comment: I'm sorry I realized I made a mistake and deleted the question; you r solution is correct.

Comment: It's cool mate...this is the place to note that the text book answer states: $\frac{{456}}{729}$

Comment: @Bak1139: sorry, the link didn't work. The probability is $\frac{496}{729}$

Comment: You are right, I probably made a typo somewhere along the way...